# Div on td with the same color

Tags: html, css

I have a div on  and they both have the same color with opacity.
The result is that the color of the div is darker than the  color.
How can I prevent it?

```html
<td align=center style="background-color:rgba(0,150,0,0.3);">
  <div style="background-color: rgba(0,150,0,0.3);">
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's darker because you have opacity and can see the `td` background coming through.

You could either:

- Remove the `div` style (it's not needed if you already have the background on the parent `td`)
- Add a solid background behind the `div` (see below)

---

```
<td align=center style="background-color:rgba(0,150,0,0.3);">
  <div style="background-color:#fff;">
    <div style="background-color: rgba(0,150,0,0.3);">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```